# IntelliJ IDEA Community + Java 11

Tags: java, intellij-idea, java-11

An article https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2018/06/java-11-in-intellij-idea-2018-2/ says that since 2018.2 IDEA support JDK-11 features. I tried to add the latest JDK-11 build to my IDEA 2018.2.3 EAP, but it says 'Cannot find JDK classes'.

The build itself is correct, as I can run jars with it.

[image: adding new jdk-11]
[image: failed]

Comment: How did you try to add the latest JDK-11? Could you post an image with this 'Cannot find JDK classes' message?

Comment: @Rumid added screenshots

Comment: Try File | Invalidate Caches | Invalidate and Restart.

Comment: @Andrey yes, that helped. Please write it as an answer. But what happened? What did it need to invalidate? I restarted it many times after update.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try File | Invalidate Caches | Invalidate and Restart.

Because of some reason (AV, perhaps), a JDK cannot find its own file on the first attempt. A negative result is then cached in IDE virtual file system. Invalidating caches helps for the case.